# How to use netsuite API to get data on mobile device?

Tags: ios, api, rest, soap, netsuite

I want to get & post data to netsuite.I have explored on google but i only go to know about **PhpToolKit** & **SuiteScript**.I want to create some custom modules in NetSuite & get data from netsuite using the API.Please help me out how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not done any coding

Comment: SO is not a coding service but a problem/solution-site. Please be more specific when posting a problem and also provide information what you already tried in order to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I have told what i have tried. PhpToolKit i get as an option.

Answer (score 2):

NetSuite offers two different methods of pulling data from an external system:

1. Web Services ([SuiteTalk](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/platform/developer/suitetalk.shtml)) provides a standardized SOAP API which has pre-built libraries for PHP, Java, and C#. NetSuite provides the WSDL for this and you can build your own client to interact with the SOAP endpoint.
2. RESTlets (sub-type of SuiteScript) provide you the ability to write your own custom NetSuite endpoints that can accept and return custom data formats. Typically, JSON is the preferred format to interface with RESTlets as it is natively supported, but you can use any format you'd like. RESTlets accept either `application/json` or `text/plain` HTTP requests.

Comment: Hello thanks.
But i want to know can i get data for my custom modules?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "custom modules", but through either RESTlets or the SOAP API you can access any custom lists, fields, or records as well as native ones.